# Google map on Customers website

Tags: google-maps

I have build few websites with google maps before 2012. But in 2012 google have made few changes and I'm confused what procedure should I follow in order to add Google map to new website.

I'm building websites for customers so how should I obtain API key? Everywhere I look there are only answers to questions like "How to add Google map to my website?". I don't want to add map to my website. I want to add map to my customer website.

Every API Key is now linked to google account so I can't use my API key as this may lead to exceed my usage limit.

Comment: Get your client to obtain their own API key, or create a dedicated account for them in they do not have one for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all is not mandantory to obtain a key for your map to function.
In case your app [exceeds the usage limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage) only then you have to take further actions.

If you want to monitor the usage create an account for your customer and obtain a key just for him.